# Flutter application not launching on run

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I was working on this application in Android Studio which was running fine on the emulator until today. I did not do any changes to the code and settings whatsoever and now when I run it, the console shows nothing nor does the emulator and after 2-3 seconds the run button goes green again.

I've tried connecting it to a real device, changed the emulator, wiped the emulator's data, ran `flutter doctor`, cleared Flutter cache, and even updated the Android Studio app, but it's still not running. And most importantly it's not even giving me an error so that I can look up for it.

The app did successfully run a couple of times today before this issue happened. I am new to Android Studio and I don't know what else I can do to fix this.

Comment: Is there an error report or maybe some logs that you could provide ?

Comment: I wish there was, but as I said there's nothing. The console is completely blank, it's like I never clicked run at all. (just the run button goes from green arrow to red block to green arrow in 3 seconds and nothing else happens)

Comment: how about permissions ? if you have any network requests you should have network permissions enabled.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I understand. I apologize for being ill-informed of the platform's decorum.

Answer (score 2):

From the top menus, navigate to `Tools -> Flutter` and click on `Flutter Clean`, then try to run again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I already did that when I posted this and it didn't work. I made a new project now and copied all the previous code to that one and it's working fine once again. But on the original project, the issue still persists. I still don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Hmmm, try to execute `flutter create .` in the folder of the project...